# Replacing concat operation in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a requirement of querying the ALL_TABLES view, based on a combination of schema name and table name.

There are two schemas "A" and "B" and they have same table "TAB1" in both of them, here my requirement is to select the table associated with schema A and not the schema B.

Currently, we are doing a concatenation operation on the table name and owner name for achieving it as shown below

There will be multiple owner and table name combinations available within a single query

```
select table_name from all_tables where concat(owner_name,table_name) in ('ATAB1','ATAB2','BTAB2','CTAB1') 
select table_name from all_tables where concat(owner_name,table_name) not in ('ATAB1','ATAB2','BTAB2','CTAB1')
```

Here there are three schemas A, B and C with their respective table name combinations

How can we achieve the same result without using the CONCAT function ?

Comment: You should look at a combination of AND and OR or IN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE 0=1
 OR (owner_name = 'A' AND table_name = 'T1')
 OR (owner_name = 'B' AND table_name = 'T2')
 OR (owner_name = 'A' AND table_name = 'T3')
```

The strange `0=1` is just to make the lines below syntactically identical for easy mainenance and/or code-generation. The optimizer removes it.

Comment: Thanks @usr, will this be more performant than the concatenation. In our case the number of table names can go beyond 1000. Which is the best optimal solution that i can go for?

Comment: Both solutions are not good for 1000s of items. They cause enormous query plans. My solution is faster in any case, though, because the optimizer can do seeks into ALL_TABLES. The concat predicate is opaque to it. Use my solution and split the query into batches. Try different batch sizes.

Comment: In SQL Server one would use a table-valued parameter. Oracle has UDT parameters and XML parameters. If you manage to get them working they are preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You could arrange the string values you need to match against into a virtual table, then use that table in a join as a filter:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM all_tables t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 'A' AS owner_name, 'TAB1' AS table_name FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 'TAB2' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 'TAB2' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 'TAB1' FROM DUAL
) s
 ON t.owner_name = s.owner_name
AND t.table_name = s.table_name
;
```

I would expect this to give the query planner more room for optimisation than your present approach gives.

Comment: Should that be `SELECT SELECT` in your subs?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle allows for multiple columns in an `IN` condition (see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions014.htm#i1033664) for some more examples).

```
select table_name
  from all_tables
 where (owner_name, table_name) in
         (('A','TAB1'), ('A','TAB2'), ('B','TAB2'), ('C','TAB1'))
```

This would probably be equivalent to [usr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540125/249624) in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks Cheran query looks simple and neat, should i use the above query in batches as mentioned by @usr for the increased no of table names predicate